# jupyter lab (python) variable names with accents

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Suppose I have a variable `x_hat`. Is there an extension which would allow jupyter to render this as `̂x`? I.e. as U+0302 followed by U+0078?

In general, it seems python does not allow combining diacritical marks to be used as variable names. Thus, for characters which do not have a specific unicode character for the accented version (e.g. x or λ) I can't have variables with hats or other diacrtical marks.

I am often writing code for numerical linear algebra algorithms, and it would be very nice if the code could match more closely with the pseudocode in papers which very commonly use accented version of symbols.

TLDR; Can I modify how text in jupyter lab is rendered?

Comment: Combining diacritical marks go **after** the letters they combine with, i.e. U+78 followed by U+302. If you do that, it works fine. E.g. `x̂ = 1+1; x̂` -> `2`

Comment: Oh, amazing. Very silly on my part. I'm still interested in the original question as I am a little hesitant to use these less-common unicode characters

Comment: Yeah, fair enough :) I don't use JupyterLab myself, but it might help to add more details, like where you want the symbols to be shown (e.g. in the code itself, debugger, and/or program output) and give a small example of your code too. Like, hypothetically, if you're already doing symbolic math with SymPy, it might be as simple as just printing the expressions you're working with.

Comment: I just want it in variable names. As an interesting side note I just learned: since the diacrtical marks can be combined we can get weird examples like this: `x̄̂=1;x̂̄=2; x̄̂==x̂̄` which evaluates to `False` since one is x hat bar and the other is x bar hat

Comment: Huh. It seems to depend on the program whether they're rendered the same. In Gnome-Terminal they're different (bar and hat stacked in different order), but in VSCode and Chrome they're the same.